# Sending Real Time Developer Notifications to a Tomcat machine for In App Purchases

Tags: android, tomcat, in-app-purchase

For our projects, we run a Java web application that produces and saves some information online. One of its features will also be registering in app purchases and its purchase changes. Because of this occasion, we decided to add "Real Time Developer Notifications" following [the official guide](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/realtime_developer_notifications). From what I understand, this works in a way that when there is an update on a purchase, this mechanism should send a notification to the web server. (If I am wrong, correct me because I am completely lost.)

From the documentation, we also require [Google Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstarts) that should trigger the notifications if I understand correctly. That's where I get lost, because I have no idea what to do. It looks like there is going to be a topic that we should subscribe, but should we do this from the same web application? Or do we need another project for this? On the documentation creating a topic will seem to be sufficient enough to trigger notifications, but I don't think so. We need some sort of implementation to receive the notifications themselves, right?

I also see another way  [using Push mechanism](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push) to receive these messages, and this way is how I designed the code so far: I thought the Pub/Sub itself would trigger the endpoint on our web application so I could process the message and send a reply to their server. If it is this easy, then I admit I cannot see how.

Please point me to the right direction to receive in app purchase changes from a Tomcat Java web application, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I just attached the web service to receive notifications by itself, and managed the requirements from there.